# If dataframe length exceeds threshold, make a new row python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns a,b,c,d

```
a b c d
1 2 nan nan
2 3 4 5 
4 5 nan nan
```

how do i reshape into 2 columns, when i am not aware of the number of rows that the result will give. (big data)

output:

```
a b 
1 2 
2 3
4 5
4 5
```

Comment: Suppose you had `1 2 3 nan` for the first row, and `4 5 6 nan` for the second. What would you want the output to be?

Comment: In that case, it should print: 1,2 in the first row,3,nan in the second row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Numpy's `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 2), columns=['a', 'b']).dropna()

     a    b
0  1.0  2.0
2  2.0  3.0
3  4.0  5.0
4  4.0  5.0
```

Comment: I believe this deletes all rows that has any nans, rather than just rows consisting entirely of nans.